# RecyclerView - notifyDataSetChanged() - Kotlin - Not Working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, okhttp

I am having an issue with reloading data in RecyclerView after the data is updated with a separate URL call. The FristFragment calls `LoadDataFromUrl` and displays the data in the Recycler View. Each Recycler's view item has a button with OnSetClickListener that calls another URL to update item's name data. After the user updates the item's name and a successful response is received, then the original `myResponse` data is updated with the new item's name. When the data is updated, I need to reload data in the Recycer View` but I can not figure it out. I spent two days trying to fix it but I can't get it running. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Data Model:

```
DataModel.kt
class MyResponse (var Status: String = "", val items: List<Items> = emptyList())
class Items(var ItemId: String = "", var ItemName: String = "")
```

Code for Recycler View:

```
Adapter.kt
var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

class MainAdapter(val myResponse: MyResponse): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){

    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)

        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_cell, parent,false)

        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {



        val item = myResponse.items.get(position)


        //there is a button for each item in the list that will call a function ButtonPressed from Frist Fragment
        holder.view.button.setOnClickListener {
        
                val firstFragment = FirstFragment()
                firstFragment.ButtonPressed(item.ItemId,item.ItemName, position)

        }
        
         holder.view.textView_ItemID = item.itemId
         holder.view.textView_Item_Name = item.itemName
    }


        class CustomViewHolder(val view: View, var Items: Item? = null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    }
}
```

Then I have a fragment Fragment.kt

```
FirstFragment.kt    
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        val rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false)
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        LoadDataFromUrl()
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context,
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
       
    }   

    //this function loads data on create view 
    fun LoadDataFromUrl(){

        
        val url = "some_url"
        val payload = "some_data_to_send"
        val requestBody = payload.toRequestBody()
        val request = Request.Builder()

            .method("POST",requestBody)
            .url(url)
            .build()

        val client =  OkHttpClient()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

                println("error")

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

                val body = response?.body?.string()

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                myResponse = gson.fromJson(body, MyResponse::class.java)

                activity?.runOnUiThread {

                    if (myResponse.Status== "200"){
                    
                        recyclerView.adapter = MainAdapter(myResponse)
                        
                    } 
                }
            }
        })
    }

    fun ButtonPressed(itemId: String, itemName: String, position: Int){

        val url = "some_another_url"
        val payload = "some_another_data_to_send"
        val requestBody = payload.toRequestBody()

        val request = Request.Builder()

                .method("POST",requestBody)
                .url(url)
                .build()

        val client =  OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("error")
            }
            
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response?.body?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val buttomPressedResponse = gson.fromJson(body, ButtonPressedResponse::class.java)

                    if (buttonPressedResponse.Status== "200") {

                        myResponse.response[position].Status = buttomPressedResponse.Status //will update existing object myResponse with a new item's name
                        
                       //this is where I have a problem
                        recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    } 
           
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following changes but I still get an error.

```
//I get this error: Fatal Exception: OkHttp Dispatcher Process. recyclerView must not be null. Then the app crashes and the view reloads. If I clcik the Button again I get an error saying: RecyclerView: No adapter atatched. Skipping layout. 
activity?.runOnUiThread {
myResponse.response[position].Status = checkInOutResponse.Status //will update existing object myResponse with updated data
recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

I also tried to run on it runOnUiTHread but nothing happens with this code

```
activity?.runOnUiThread {
    myResponse.response[position].Status = checkInOutResponse.Status //will update existing object myResponse with updated data
recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: Run your request in a ViewModel so it can outlive the Activity/Fragment through configuration changes. Have the request update a LiveData instead of directly modifying a view. In your Fragment, observe the LiveData and update the adapter from the observer. Also, don't create view-related properties outside View/Activity/Fragment subclasses, or you will have memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Create `var myResponse: MyResponse` variable in Adapter

```
Adapter.kt
var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

class MainAdapter(val myResponseInit: MyResponse): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){
    var myResponse: MyResponse
    
    myResponse = myResponseInit

    fun submitMyResponse(data: MyResponse) {
        myResponse = data
    }

    //Rest of the code onCreateViewHolder etc.
}
```

Call `submitMyResponse()` function and `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter everytime you receive response.