# Observer on LiveData in RecyclerView - Kolin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

how can I implement LiveData Observer in the Recycler View? I have a global var `someDataChanged' that gets updated from another Fragment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class GlobalActivity {

    companion object {
        someDataChanged = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    }
}
```

Then in the Adapter.kt for the RecyclerView I need to listen if the `someDataChanged`. I have the following code:

```
Adapter.kt
var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

class MainAdapter(val myResponse: MyResponse): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){

    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    
        //Error: this is not recognized.  
        GlobalActivity.someDataChanged`.observe(this, Observer{
            println("Data Changed")
        })

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_cell, parent,false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
 
        //some code
        class CustomViewHolder(val view: View, var myPass: Passes? = null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be observing in your adapter. Instead observe from your activity or fragment and pass the information to the adapter.

Comment: Also I don't know your specific scenario but having a singleton piece of `LiveData` seems a bit scary... Secondly, even if you were observing inside the adapter, `onCreateViewHolder` would not be the place to do it. You'd end up with it triggering multiple times per change.

Comment: Hi, how I would I pass the information back to the adapter? I just posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024250/recyclerview-notifydatasetchanged-kotlin-not-working. I can't get recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged() working on the RecyclerView. I though that LiveData could be a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Ah I see. Workarounds should be for when there's no possible other solution. I wouldn't recommend implementing a workaround before even solving your first problem. I'll take a look at your other question.

Answer (score 1):

in `RecyclerView.Adapter` need to override onCreateViewHolder, pass `lifeCycleOwner`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    val lifeCycleOwner = parent.context as LifecycleOwner
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
    return ItemViewHolder(view, lifeCycleOwner)
}
```

your inner class constructor, should have `lifecycleOwner` as param

```
inner class ItemViewHolder(view: View, private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
```

then you can use code as normally

```
mutableLiveData.observe(lifecycleOwner) { /** your logic handle **/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: RecylerViews notifies about changes on the same instance of list, but LiveData only notifies changes to it's observers on reassigning its value.

Why don't you try using a ListAdapter instead of simple RecyclerView.Adapter?

here's a sample of how would you implement it:
firstly create your adapter class; inheriting ListAdapter:

```
class EmployeeRecyclerViewAdapter(
private val onClickListener: (Employee) -> Unit) : ListAdapter<Employee, EmployeeViewHolder>(EmployeeDiffCallback()) {
```

Implementing a ListAdapter is pretty much the same as RecyclerView.Adapter, there are some differences though like creating DiffCallback which I won't get into that.

Then, observe the list value like the snippet below and notify updates on the adapter:

```
viewModel.employeeListLiveData.observe(this) { employeeList ->

        cardViewListLoading.visibility = when {
            employeeList.isEmpty() -> View.VISIBLE
            else -> View.GONE
        }

        (recyclerView.adapter as EmployeeRecyclerViewAdapter).submitList(employeeList)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood your question but if you want to update your recycler view every time the liveData is updated you should create something like this:

```html
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        adapter = MyAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        viewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, Observer { newContent ->
            adapter.updateContent(newContent)
        })
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _myLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val myLiveData: LiveData<String> = _myLiveData
   
    // You should call this to update you liveData
    fun updateInfo(newInfo: String) {
        _myLiveData.value = newInfo
    }
}

class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private var content: String = ""
    ...
    
    fun updateInfo(newString: String) {
        content = newString
        notifyDataSetChanged() //or you can implement a DiffUtil.Callback
    }
    
}
```